# How do I efficiently keep track of maximum responses and location of the responses when processing an image?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, opencv, heap

Say I'm processing an image and calculating some value at every pixel in the image like so:

```
int i = 0;
uchar* p;
p = imgMat.ptr<uchar>(0);
for ( i = 0; i < imgMat.rows * imgMat.cols; ++i)
{
    int val = some calculation that returns an int;
}
```

I want to keep track of the top 50, say, values returned while processing the image. I also want to keep track of the location in the image where that value came from (x, y or pointer, doesn't matter).

I looked into heaps as an efficient way to keep track of the top response values but I don't know how I can also keep track of the location in the image that returned those responses. Basically I need an fast, efficient way to keep track of the top *n* responses in the image and the location of those responses, if you see what I mean. Thanks greatly in advance for any help.

Comment: What about storing the responses in a map like `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int>` where the key holds row and col, and the value is the result of the calculation?

Comment: I would consider writing a struct or class to hold the data and overwrite the `operator<` for it. This way you would get a pretty self descriptive solution you can easily store in any sort of container or heap and sort it.

Comment: @user0042 I don't think this would work for me as maps are not easily sortable, therefore it would be hard to get the top 50 values.

Comment: @user7381795 You can also use a `std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>>` and provide your own sorting function.

Comment: To @muXXmit2X 's suggestion I add a `std::priority_queue`. Push the new element in and if over 50 elements, `pop`.